# Can Raman scattering (vibrational energy) of a diatomic molecule be described using work instead of potential energy?

Tags: visible-light, work, raman-spectroscopy

From the literature, a diatomic model is often used to describe vibrational energy due to the inelastic scattering of light: two bodies (to represent charges) connected by a massless spring (to represent electrostatic forces, etc.). The electric field of the incident photon causes a temporary dipole moment, displacing the bodies (increasing the intranuclear distance). Ignoring the fact that this is an anharmonic oscillator, the governing equations are simply
$$F=ma\\
F=-kx.$$
I remember from high-school physics, the potential energy can be described using $U=\frac{1}{2}kx^{2}$, but after taking some college engineering courses, I'm more used to describing the equations as
$$F_{i}^{(e)}=m_{i}\ddot{u}_{ii}+\sum_{j=1}^{n}k_{ij}u_{j}\\
Q_{i}=k_{in}c_{in}Q_{n}\\
W=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}c_{ij}Q_{i}Q_{j}.$$
To me, this is intuitive, because the electric field of the laser light is thought to perform some work on the molecule by displacing the charges. But from what I could glean from a few internet articles, energy level diagrams of the electronic states are what is used, and therefore are described with potential energy of the system instead. Is that because the molecules' energy state is what determines whether is it Stokes or anti-Stokes? And the molecule itself is what determines the photon's final scattered frequency (which is the measurement of interest)?

Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.